# Google Analytics Data Fetch

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

How to get Google analytics data in our database and after first time authorize data all data store and automatically update daily without authorization.

once I authorize in Google account and after authorize and store data in our data base and again login in site so in this time how to update all Google analytics data in our database please help me.

I wait for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the core reporting api v4. Whenever you perform a request you get a response with a pageToken. The final response is the one that returns a null pageToken. This is the key criterion to get all the data you want! Keep in mind that each request requests at most 10000 rows of data! You need some credentials to get authorized for accessing google analytics. There are two ways: The first one is using a json file and the second one using the .p12 file. In bothe cases you need a view Id. For more details you can have a look at core reporting api v4 documentation! Each time you perform a request one more authentication is triggered! It is inevitable! GA api is extremely fast though!

Answer (score 0):

if u want to access google analyitics data first u must use offline so we can get refresh token this referesh token store in your database if u want to again u r data without authorization u can use this refresh token and generate access token so now each and every time u can get updated google analytics data by using offline access .........